# Is there a way to bulk import csv data into cosmos db gremlin API Azure?

Tags: neo4j, graphql, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am new to Azure Cosmos db and i have to import data into my cosmos db account.

I have tried out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin/bulk-executor-dotnet#java

In this link they have imported some randomly generated values from a predefined seed values: [SeedGenerationValues.java](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-graph-bulk-executor/blob/main/java/src/main/java/com/azure/graph/bulk/sample/SeedGenerationValues.java) (Or I think so.)

Is there a way where I can input a few csv and the schema of the graph and get the complete graph?

I have tried to change each record into a gremlin query and tried to insert the data from local: [DataWeekender-DataLoad.ipynb](https://github.com/sadukie/dataweekender-cu5-gremlin-api/blob/main/DataWeekender-DataLoad.ipynb)

But this is very inefficient and takes lot of time to import a large dataset (with 1 million records). Is there a way like the bulk import provided by Microsoft Azure which imports the data efficiently into the gremlin cosmos db?

Is there a repository which I can use where I can simply give the csv data's and the schema as input and get the complete graph, just like how we do in neo4j and import data?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to bulk import csv data into cosmos db gremlin API Azure

To import `.csv` file into Azure Cosmos DB Gremlin API you can use below code. Below is the `.NET` code which imports data into Cosmos DB Gremlin API container.

```cs
class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = "*****";
            CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(connectionString);
            var database = client.GetDatabase("newdb");
            var container = database.GetContainer("Graph1");

            using (var reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\****\\****\\Desktop\\MyTrails\\firstFile.csv"))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                var records = csv.GetRecords<MyData>();

                foreach (var record in records)
                {
                    dynamic vertex = new
                    {
                        id = record.Id.ToString(),
                        label = "Person",
                        name = record.Name,
                        age = record.Age
                    };

                    try
                    {
                        await container.CreateItemAsync(vertex);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Failed to insert record with id{record.Id}: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyData
    {
        [Index(0)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Index(1)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Index(2)]
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response ! . Here you have converted each record into a node or edge and added it to the database. Is there a way where we can input the csv and the schema of the graph and it automatically takes the structure of the node based on the columns of the csv .

Because in the project i am working it has 40 csv with 50000 rows each . so in this approach it takes a lot of time to import the data and also it is a tedious task to convert each table to its desired node or edge structure.

if not the working code atleast the idea on how to proceed would be really appreciated.

Comment: Or is there any other service in azure which will do this task for us ?